# link_to Show page takes me to the index page Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to have a dashboard in my app that lists all the reviews the user has. The problem that i have is when i click on the post that the user gave a review in , it takes me to the index page of all the posts instead of the show page of the specific post. This is the line of code i am having issue with  `<td><%= link_to review.post.title , posts_path(@post) %></td>` 
. Here's my code:

**views/pages/dashboard.html.erb**

```
<div class="align-left">



<div class="col-md-2">
<h5><%= @user.name %></h5>


</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<h3>My Posts</h3>

<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= post.title %></td>
          <td><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</td>
          <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>|<%= link_to "Destroy", post_path(post), method: :delete %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<br>

<h3>My Reviews</h3>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Place</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
        <tr>
         <td><%= link_to review.post.title , posts_path(@post) %></td> 
        <td><%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago</td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
```

**the Rake route file**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a instance variable @posts not @post on dashboard.html.erb page.
And you can get post by review.post, like:-

```
<td><%= link_to review.post.title , post_path(review.post) %></td>
```

Also, Instead of call association again and again you can do this:-

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <tr>
    <% review_post = review.post %>
     <td><%= link_to review_post.title , post_path(review_post) %></td> 
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be `<%= link_to review.post.title, post_path(@post) %>`,
or just `<%= link_to review.post.title, @post %>`
not `<%= link_to review.post.title, posts_path(@post) %>`.

Comment: also instead of setting the variable elsewhere, `post_path(review.post)` should work

Answer (score 0):

You have not check your routes properly:
[image]

`posts_path` is for `index` method and for `show` method it is `post_path` with `id` or object.

Use:

```
<td><%= link_to review.post.title , post_path(@post) %></td>
```